# How can make API call to an external jar file from iOS UI Automation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jar, ios-ui-automation

Currently, I need to call some APIs from an external JAR file within my iOS UI Automation test script.  For example, in my UI Automation test script, I can input an email address and send a email to that address. Next, I need to make an API call to an external JAR file which will mark that email address is been verified. Then, I can do some following actions in the app UI.  However, I have not find any documentation about that.

Could anyone provide any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/UIAHost/UIAHost.html).